# NSIS script doesn't display service status

Tags: nsis

I created section at the end of script which suppose to display myservice status, but no messagebox displays after exec.
What might be the reason?

````
Section "Create Service"
  ExecShellWait '' 'sc.exe' 'create myservice error= "severe" displayname= "myservice" type= "own" start= "auto" binpath= "$INSTDIR\MyService.exe"' SW_HIDE
SectionEnd

Section "Start Service"
  ExecShellWait '' 'sc.exe' 'start myservice' SW_HIDE
SectionEnd

Section "Ensure Running"
  StrCpy $R0 '"$SYSDIR\cmd.exe" /c "sc QUERY myservice | FIND /C "RUNNING""'
  nsExec::ExecToStack '$R0'
  Pop $R1  # contains return code
  Pop $R2  # contains output
  ${If} $R1 == "0"    
  DetailPrint "checking if command is success"
    ${If} $R2 == "1"
        MessageBox mb_ok "myservice is Running"   # it's running
    ${Else}
        MessageBox mb_ok "Not Running"        # it's not running
    ${EndIf}
  ${Else}
  DetailPrint "command failed"
  ${EndIf}  
SectionEnd ```


 nsExec::ExecToStack /OEM '$R0' didn't change anything. During installation it rushes to finish page after sc exec ..Do I need to add additional page page here ?

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE ..\license.rtf
; Page custom pageRegistration
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
````

Comment: If you check in the services manager, is it actually running?

Comment: yup, in the service manager application shows running after installation.

nsExec::ExecToStack /OEM '$R0' didn't change anything. During installation it rushes to finish page after sc exec ..Do I need to add additional page page here ?

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE ..\license.rtf
; Page custom pageRegistration
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Comment: !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_NOAUTOCLOSE at the start of your nsi

Comment: Thank you for reply..
After adding above line it shows command failed.

Comment: When I run command on windows it shows:

when service was running..
C:\Users\xxxx> sc QUERY myservice | FIND /C "RUNNING"
1
After i uninstalled.
C:\Users\xxxx> sc QUERY myservice | FIND /C "RUNNING"
0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the output I can only guess that there is some sort of Unicode issue.

Change `nsExec::ExecToStack '$R0'` to `nsExec::ExecToStack /OEM '$R0'`.

That being said, I don't know if the RUNNING string is always in English. There are several service plug-ins and macros on the NSIS wiki you can use instead.

Or you can use this:

```
!include "LogicLib.nsh"
!include "Win\COM.nsh"
!include "Win\Propkey.nsh"
Function IsServiceRunning
Exch $0
Push $1
StrCpy $1 $0
!insertmacro ComHlpr_CreateInProcInstance {13709620-C279-11ce-A49E-444553540000} {A4C6892C-3BA9-11D2-9DEA-00C04FB16162} r0 "" ; IE5+?
${If} $0 P<> 0
    System::Call "$0->36(wr1,@r1)i.s"
    ${IUnknown::Release} $0 ""
    Pop $0
    ${If} $0 >= 0
        StrCpy $0 0
        Push $2
        ${V_GetVT} $1 r2
        ${V_GetBOOL} $1 r1
        ${If} $2 = ${VT_BOOL}
        ${AndIf} $1 <> ${VARIANT_FALSE}
            StrCpy $0 1
        ${EndIf}
        Pop $2
    ${Else}
        StrCpy $0 0
    ${EndIf}
${EndIf}
Pop $1
Exch $0
FunctionEnd

Section "Example"
Push "RemoteRegistry"
Call IsServiceRunning
Pop $0
DetailPrint "RemoteRegistry running=$0"

Push "Themes"
Call IsServiceRunning
Pop $0
DetailPrint "Themes running=$0"
SectionEnd
```